# Defining a function name that starts with a number (in Python 3)?

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

I have tried creating the following function:
`def 3utr():
   do_something()`.
However, I get a SyntaxError. Replacing the "3" by "three" fixes the problem.

My questions are:

- Why is it a syntax error?
- Is there a way to have a function name start with a number in Python 3?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is a syntax error because the language specification does not allow identifiers to start with a digit. So it’s not possible to have function names (which are identifiers) that start with digits in Python.

> `identifier ::=  (letter|"_") (letter | digit | "_")*`

[Python 2 Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers)

> Within the ASCII range (U+0001..U+007F), the valid characters for identifiers are the same as in Python 2.x: the uppercase and lowercase letters A through Z, the underscore _ and, **except for the first character, the digits 0 through 9**.

[Python 3 Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers)

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to programming, so I find it often difficult to know where to look for these kind of details (without going through EVERY page of the book ;).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to be distinctive.

You can add '_' in front of an identifier

For instance

```
def _3utr():
```

Then call the function

```
_3utr()
```

Answer (score -1):

One workaround is use Roman numerals:

```
>>> def xxiv():
...     print("ok\n")
... 
>>> xxiv()
ok
```